# How can I tightly align a checkbox with a text input form control using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align a checkbox with a text input. I would like the text box to be a form control, so that it right aligns with the other inputs on the page. However, if I do this, it becomes a block element and there is a line break after the checkbox. If I don't use the form-control class, the input box isn't wide enough and it doesn't look right compared to the rest of the form. If I use the grid layout, there is too much space in between the checkbox and the text box.

The image below represents the following code:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your own vendor name here ..." class="form-control" />
</div>
```

[image: chextbox]

Answer (score 2):

Simple class like `form-inline` and `form-group` would help you on this.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your own vendor name here ..." class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2yao3x5r/

However, from bootstrap documentation

> This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px
>   wide

Besides, I have a suggestion if your checkbox belongs to your input to use `input-group`

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
</div>
```

If you have a smaller than 768px viewport, I suggest to use `.row` and `.col` modifier. e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your own vendor name here ..." class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Input-Group Add-on](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios) component for checkboxes/radios. And you can always style the input-group box if it doesn't work for your specific form setup.

See example Snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.input-group-addon.my-addon {
  background: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well">Default</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
      </span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="well">Added Styling</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon my-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
      </span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-inline or form-horizontal

- Inline-form 
  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline
- Horizontal-form
  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

or

You have to add "display:inline-block" to your input controls

Answer (score 0):

You could use `input-group-addon` and style the checkbox as a label for the input.

For more precise control, but less clean, you can add some CSS to the controls themselves:

```
#inputText {
      margin-left: 20px;
}
#inputCheckbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

HTML (with grid system):

```
<div class="col-md-2">XX</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your own vendor name here ..."
       class="form-control" id="inputText" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left" id="inputCheckbox" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">XX</div>
```